# Error print a csv file per line in python looping

Tags: python, csv

I try to print the csv file:

```
file_in = 'idtwitterOut.csv'
dataset = open(file_in, "r")

for line in dataset:
    print(line)
```

But, the result is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2782: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there has a special treatment for csv file in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is file character set encoding error which is even written in error. By using right character encoding utf8 would be resolved-
replace the line

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
```

with

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r',encoding='utf8') as csvFile:
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a encoding issue, so use `utf8`:

```
dataset = open(file_in, "r", encoding="utf8")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a module available in python called `csv` to read `.csv` files.

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas library it will work this way:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
print(csv_data)
```